# Access - Select Query that returns the "one" from a One-to-Many Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my first post, so I apologize in advance for any newbie mistakes.  I expect that what I am trying to do is not difficult, but I lack the vocabulary to find my answer by searching.

I have two one-to-many tables:

```
tblLegToXacts
-------------
Leg (many)  
Xact (one)
```

```
tblTorsoToLegs
--------------
Torso (many)  
Leg (one)
```

I would like a select query to return the `Torso` when the inputted criteria is multiple `Xacts` that are part of the same `Leg` which is part of the same `Torso`.

My multiple attempts at a successful query all return zero records.  I tried a simplified query that only attempts to return the `Torso` when the inputted criteria is two `Legs` that are part of the same `Torso`, but again, no joy.

Here is the SQL from Access:

```sql
SELECT tblTorsoToLegs.Torso  
FROM (tblTorsoToLegs  
INNER JOIN tblLegToXacts ON tblTorsoToLegs.Leg = tblLegToXacts.Leg)   
INNER JOIN tblLegToXacts AS tblLegToXacts_1 ON tblTorsoToLegs.Leg = tblLegToXacts_1.Leg  
WHERE (((tblLegToXacts.Leg)=998)   
AND ((tblLegToXacts_1.Leg)=1022));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I tried to format the SQL by indenting the SQL keywords, but it was removed when I posted.

Comment: Could you please post some sample data alongside the expected result for the given sample data?

Comment: Hi @DavidNorris, welcome. What would be very helpful for us is to see what you are currently getting when you run your query, vs what you are expecting to receive as output. Can you please provide that for us?

Comment: Additionally, why are you filtering on leg if you are concerned with Xacts?